# Is there a single line way to run a command in a Python venv?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, virtualenv

I have a command that only runs correctly inside a Python virtual environment I've configured (as intended). I know that I can run the command as

```
$ cmd args
```

once I've activated the venv. But (due to the constraints of the tool I'm using) I need to activate run (and deactivate?) in one line: something equivalent to running

```
$ activate_somehow cmd args
```

outside the command line.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 21):

You can generally run something in a virtual environment simply by using a fully qualified path to the script.  For example, if I have:

```
virtualenv .venv
```

Then I can install something into that virtual environment without activating it by running:

```
.venv/bin/pip install foo
```

This should be true for anything installed using standard Python mechanisms.

Comment: Mmm but what if the thing you want to run isn't specifically defined in the virtual environment? It could be a system command like `flake8` which needs to know about your env but you might not want to install it again locally just in order for this to work.

Comment: (That's not a particularly compelling example, I admit.)

Comment: I would just install it inside your virtual environment.  I think that trying to mix "stuff inside your virtual environment" with "stuff outside the virtual environment" is a recipe for confusion (e.g., different versions of python, or different versions of particular modules installed, etc).  But @tripleee has a suggestion if you really want to do that.

Comment: For flake8 in particular I *always* install that into my venv, because I rely on that for syntax error checking in my editor so it needs to be using the same version of python for which I am currently developing...

Comment: Is there are `pipenv run` style mechanism for `python3 -m venv`?

Answer (score 5):

After looking into the generated `bin/activate` script, it seems like the only thing relevant to python is the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable, so this should be enough to get going:

```
$ env VIRTUAL_ENV=path/to/venv python ...
```

Note that the python executable in the `bin` directory of target environment is just a symlink to globally installed interpreter, which does nothing other that setting process executable path. Assuming the program does not make use of it, utilizing the main binary itself seems harmless. In case you have installed a package which in turn installs some executables, just specify the absolute path:

```
$ env VIRTUAL_ENV=path/to/venv path/to/venv/bin/executable
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [venv-run](https://github.com/guludo/venv-run) which should do what you ask:

```
pip install venv-run
venv-run cmd args
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple wrapper script which runs `activate`, executes your command, and then deactivates simply by exiting the script in which your environment was activated.

```
#!/bin/sh
. ${venv-./env}/bin/activate
"$@"
```

This lets you set the environment variable `venv` to the path of the environment you want to use, or else uses `./env` if it is unset. Perhaps a better design would be to pass the env as the first parameter:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$1"/bin/activate
shift
"$@"
```

Either way, save this somewhere in your `PATH` (`$HOME/bin` is a common choice for your private scripts) and give it executable permission.

Comment: I really like this solution, as it is simple and flexible and does not break much. At least that is what it looks like. Note that the .venv is relative to the current path, not the folder where the target script is located! I'd like to suggest to change the dot "." to "source", as it is much clearer what it does though.

Comment: `source` is a Bash synonym, but does not work in `sh` scripts.

Comment: These days though, I'd recommend the answer by larsks

Comment: I am still wondering why that works. For me the venv python just points to my normal system python. But it will magically pick up all my venv modules. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @NicoHood Running Python from that location adds the `lib` directory from the virtual environment to the end of `sys.path`. I don't see explicit documentation for this in [the `sys` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) but that's what's happening. I'm sure there will be existing questions about the precise mechanism for this elsewhere on this site. Try e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871891/how-does-activating-a-python-virtual-environment-modify-sys-path

Comment: It is still not clear to my. On my system the venv python file is just a symlink. How could that do anything different to the "real" system binary? Or does the system binary check from WHERE is was started, so it can follow back to the symlink location? That would make sense, but I am not sure if it is possible. It seems it is the only option?

Comment: Indeed, the binary does know which path name you used when you invoked it. (This is also how Bash knows whether it's being invoked as `bash` or `sh`.) The question I linked in my previous comment has a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[Larsk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174818/3772123) is probably cleaner, but this is another possible way.
Assuming you use UNIX and your user is `user` and you have a virtual environment in home (any) directory, ie `/home/user/venv`, you can make a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
export VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/user/venv
export PATH=/home/user/venv/bin:$PATH
python3 "$@"
```

We can make this script executable (eg call it `venv-python3` and do `chmod +x venv-python3`) and call it as such, or put it some place discoverable in PATH - let's say alongside python. Assuming you have sudo rights:

```
sudo cp venv-python3 /usr/bin/venv-python3
```

Then we can call that instead of the python callable. Since the variables are set within the script, explicit call on deactivate is not necessary at exit.

Example:

```
user@machine ~ % venv-python3 --help
```

This works for at least for virtualenv version 20.0.17 but if adopted, you should be keeping an eye on what variables `bin/activate` sets, if this ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute the python file using a virtual environment in a single line of command on windows.

```
venv\Scripts\activate&&python fall_detector.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed pgadmin4 in my home directory in a virtual environment called "pgadmin4".

I use fish shell and it runs perfectly fine with:

```
~/pgadmin4/bin/python3 ~/pgadmin4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Just in case this helps somebody.