# How does activating a python virtual environment modify sys.path?

Tags: python, bash, python-venv

I create my python virtual environment using:

```
python3 -m venv venv3
```

to activate, I `source venv3/bin/activate`.

`venv3/bin/activate` doesn't appear to be all that complex:

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
        hash -r
    fi

    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/pi/django-test/venv3"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "$PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x(venv3) " != x ] ; then
    PS1="(venv3) $PS1"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
    hash -r
fi
```

I can see it modifying $PATH, and $PS1, creating a `deactivate` function, and even backing up old variables that it modifies so it can restore them when the user runs the `deactivate` function. All this makes sense.

The one thing I don't see is where python's sys.path is modified. On my system, this is what I see:

sys.path outside of virtual environment:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

sys.path inside of virtual environment:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/django-test/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Clearly, sys.path gets modified at some point, somehow. This makes sense, since that's how python knows where to find the third-party python libraries that are installed. I would think that this is the main feature of the virtual environment, but I can't see where it gets set.

I'm not trying to accomplish anything - mostly just curious.

Comment: I believe Python uses `sys.prefix` (which will refer to the virtual environment) to initialize `sys.path`.

Comment: I can confirm that outside of the virtual environment, `sys.prefix` is set to `/usr` on my system, while inside the virtual environment, it's set to `/home/pi/django-test/venv3`. What sets this variable? It doesn't appear that the `activate` script does. How does the variable get used by `sys.path`?

Comment: The value of `sys.prefix` is determined by Python itself, based on where the interpreter is installed. When your virtual environment is activated, your `PATH` is modified so that `python` resolves to the executable (which may just be a symlink) stored in your virtual environment directory.

Comment: How does venv create the modified executable? Looking at the source it just looks like it copies things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sys.path` is initiated in `site.py`, it is set using the relative path of `sys.prefix`, which is the path of python executable inside the virtual environment.

if the virtual environment is created **without** option `--system-site-packages`, which is the default, the config value of key `include-system-site-packages` set to `false` in `pyvenv.cfg` .

`virtualenv` has an identical option `--system-site-packages`, but it [will write](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py#L1397-L1399) a file named `no-global-site-packages.txt` into the `site` dir of venv as a flag.

during python startup, `site.py` is executed, it will [check `pyvenv.cfg` config file to set `sys.path`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/00278d4e616315e64557bff014574c079e6e96ff/Lib/site.py#L480-L502):

> If “pyvenv.cfg” (a bootstrap configuration file) contains the key “include-system-site-packages” set to anything other than “true” (case-insensitive), the system-level prefixes will not be searched for site-packages; otherwise they will.

if venv is created with `virtualenv`, `site.py`
in venv is [a modified version](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/site.py), it [check the existence](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/site.py#L763-L771) of file `no-global-site-packages.txt`, if this flag file not exists, system-wide site package path will be added to `sys.path`, which is infered from `sys.real_prefix`.

update 2022: lastest virtualenv also use `pyvenv.cfg`.

hope this could answer your question.

Comment: Why assume OP is using `virtualenv` and base your answer on this if question _explicitly_ says the environment was created with `python3 -m venv`???

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that activating a virtual environment does *not* change `sys.path`. `sys.path` is determined once Python starts up; see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.path. What the virtual environment does, by adjusting your `PATH` environment variable, is change what interpreter actually runs when you simply run `python`.

Comment: When you create a virtual environment, there's an optional argument called `--system-site-packages` that allows the python that is inside the virtual environment to use third-party packages that were installed system-wide. While I can now see how python can figure out where to find libraries by using relative paths in relation to its executable, there must be some way for the virtualenv to tell python to include/exclude system-wide python libraries when `--system-site-packages` is used - isn't there? This setting effects `sys.path`. I don't see anything in `activate` related to it either.